# An inequality from the "Interlacing-1" paper

Tags: linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, geometric-group-theory, convex-optimization, spectral-graph-theory

This question is in reference to this paper, http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v182-n1-p07-p.pdf (or its arxiv version,  http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4132)

For the argument to work one seems to need that for the symmetric $\pm 1$ signing adjacency matrix of the graph, $A_s$, it holds that,

$$max-root( \sum_{s \in \{0,1\}^m } det(xI - A_s )  ) \leq max-root(\mathbb{E}_{s \in \{0,1\}^m} [det(xI-A_s)]) $$

- But why should this inequality be true?

---

and the argument works because the polynomial on the RHS is the matching polynomial whose largest root is bounded by $2\sqrt{d-1}$ for $d$-regular graphs and the common interlacing property and Lemma $4.2$ on page $8$ together imply that there exists a signing $s'$ such that $\lambda_{max}(  det(xI - A_{s'} )  ) \leq \lambda_{max}( \sum_{s \in \{0,1\}^m } det(xI - A_s )  ) $

Comment: The hyperlink only works if it's being accessed from a site with a subscription to Annals. It might be helpful to at least indicate what the paper is called and who it's by for those accessing from elsewhere.

Comment: I have added the arxiv link to the paper. Can you kindly help with the question?

Comment: No. I have no idea about the question, but until I located the paper, I couldn't even say that.

Comment: When you write $\mathbb E_{s\in\{0,1\}^m}$ on the right, is this just expectation with respect to the uniform distribution on the hypercube? If so the two polynomials on the left and right sides just differ by a factor of $2^m$ and so have the same roots.